# Simple Probability

Tags: probability

In a population, the probability of a person's birthday being in a particular month is $1/12$. $N$ people are chosen so the probability of at least one of them having their birthday in january exceeds $0.9$ 
Find the least possible value of $n$

Comment: What progress have you made so far?

Comment: (11/12)^n < 0.1

Comment: Used logs to calculate a value for n. Not sure if its right, or if this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Done. You can definitely take log of both sides.

$n\log \frac {11} {12}<-1$

Notice that I took log of base 10. It is an increasing function and hence I preserved the inequality sign. If you would have taken base $<1$ you would have to reverse inequality sign.

Now multiply both sides by $-1$ and reverse inequality(multiplying by negative number)

$n (\log 12-\log 11)>1$

$n>1/(\log(12)-\log(11))$

As n is a natural number, $n=\lceil\frac{1}{\log 12 - \log 11}\rceil$. Whete $\lceil{ \text{ x }}\rceil$ is the smallest integer above x.

Quick google tells us that $n=27$

Comment: Got the same answer, thanks!